# EF Core Migration - PK Violation when seeding data

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, seeding, ef-core-3.0

I am working with an existing project that has a database with what appears to be manually created data via SQL Server \ SSMS.

Further down the project someone else has come and created a seed data \ configuration file. This is where I have been introduced into the solution and have created a new migration file, and found that I am getting an error:

> PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AnswerTypes'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'forms.AnswerTypes'. The duplicate key value is (1)

Looking through Azure Pipelines, this appears to have been an issue since the configuration file was created.

The configure code is

```
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<FieldType> builder)
    {
        if (builder == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));
        }

        builder.ToTable("FieldTypes", FormEngineSchemas.Forms);

        // TODO: convert to enum
        builder.HasData(
            new FieldType
            {
                FieldTypeId = 1,
                FieldTypes = "NUMBER"
            },
            new FieldType
            {
                FieldTypeId = 2,
                FieldTypes = "DROPDOWN"
            },
            new FieldType
            {
                FieldTypeId = 3,
                FieldTypes = "DATE"
            });
    }
```

The upscript is

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
    migrationBuilder.InsertData(
        schema: "forms",
        table: "AnswerTypes",
        columns: new[] { "AnswerTypeId", "AnswerTypes" },
        values: new object[,]
        {
            { 1, "Range" },
            { 2, "Length" },
            { 3, "regex" }
        });      
}
```

I would be grateful if someone could help advise me how to get passed this as I am looking to not have to delete the existing data in the database because I dont want to risk potential orphaned records, or risk failed deletes.

I have had a look round and this is the closest that I can see to my issue

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12324

Looking here it looks like the seeding has been done correctly

https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/seeding

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/august/data-points-deep-dive-into-ef-core-hasdata-seeding

So, questions I have are;

1. If the database was all created and seeded from the beginning and all worked fine would all subsequent migrations work ok and not attempt to seed them again.
2. What is the best way to to get around this issue.
3. Is there anything I might have missed or not considered?

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not want to lose data, you can consider using `migrationBuilder.UpdateData()` instead of `migrationBuilder.InsertData()`. The InserData method will add new records to the DB while UpdateData will search for and update existing records in the DB.

Make sure you have EF Core v2.1 and up for this to work.